# xpath find element's grandparent

Tags: xpath

I'm a bit stuck with getting a grandparent element by Xpath. Unfortunately, my tries were unsuccessful.

**HTML**

```
<span class="fsm fwn fcg">
  <a href="bla bla">
    <abbr>
      <span class="timestampContent" id="js_19">21 mins</span>
    </abbr>
  </a>
</span>
```

i need to get the `<a href="bla bla">` element as the grandparent for `<span class="timestampContent" id="js_19">21 mins</span>`

i tried something like the following:
`//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), 21 mins)]../..` or
`../..//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), 21 mins)]`

and some other options, but it didn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your first try is close, only a `/` before `..` was missing (and missing quotes around '21 mins', which I believe was just a typo) :

```
//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '21 mins')]/../..
```

Alternatively, you can do it the other way around i.e by selecting element that has grand child `span` of certain criteria :

```
//*[*/span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '21 mins')]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose text in quotes, and a `/` must come between the `]` and the `..`:

```
//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '21 mins')]/../..
```

However, a perhaps more reliable way to achieve this in case the markup changes in future, is to not explicitly go up two levels but to find the first grandparent `a` tag:

```
//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '21 mins')]/ancestor::a[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(),'21 mins')]/ancestor::a[@href='bla bla']
```

Here "and" condition makes the element more specified. You are specifically looking for an element  that has the specific href('bla bla'). If you want to find the specific element ,which is a parent of a specific child, you use the ancestor:: command.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47410585/edit) the answer and add the explanation in it, instead of adding adding in comments :)

Answer (score 2):

You could try

`//span[@class='timestampContent' and contains(text(), '21 mins')]/../parent::a`

This is a more direct way to the `a` element you want so you won't need to add `[1]` or `[@href='bla bla']` like when using `ancestor`.

This could be helpful when pointing to a specific `div` element directly without needing to specify its attributes.